# Stored Procedure takes 30 seconds but Report takes 10 minutes

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am using SQL Server 2005 and I have been trying to fix this for a while now. I have tried the parameter sniffing and with recompile but neither have worked.

When executing the stored procedure, it takes 30 seconds and the report takes around 10 minutes. I'm not going to post the whole stored procedure because it is 300 lines, but I'll post the first bit of it. I am lost, and so are my coworkers as to why this is so slow.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_PermitAllData]
    @datey datetime
with recompile
AS
BEGIN
   Set NoCount On

   Declare @date datetime
   Set @date = @datey

   --Permit11
   select 
       MDate,
       isnull(NumbBreaker, 0) NumbBreaker,
       isnull(Steel20T, 0) Steel20T,
       isnull(Steel9T, 0) Steel9T,
       isnull(Ductile, 0) Ductile,
       isnull(IMF,0) IMF,
       isnull((select sum(NumbBreaker) from Permit p 
               where MDate>= dateadd(month,-11,Permit.MDate) and MDate<= dateadd(month,-1,Permit.MDate)),0) NumbBreaker11,
       isnull((select sum(Steel20T) from Permit p 
               where MDate>= dateadd(month,-11,Permit.MDate) and MDate<=dateadd(month,-1,Permit.MDate) and MDate>='10/1/2008'),0) Steel20T11,
       isnull((select sum(Steel9T) from Permit p where MDate>= dateadd(month,-11,Permit.MDate) and MDate<= dateadd(month,-1,Permit.MDate)and MDate>='10/1/2008'),0) Steel9T11,
       isnull((select sum(Ductile) from Permit p where MDate>= dateadd(month,-11,Permit.MDate) and MDate<= dateadd(month,-1,Permit.MDate)),0) Ductile11,
       isnull((select sum(IMF) from Permit p where  MDate>= dateadd(month,-11,Permit.MDate) and MDate<= dateadd(month,-1,Permit.MDate)),0) IMF11
    Into #Permit11 
    from 
       Permit 
    where 
       MDate between dateadd(month,-2,@date) AND @date

    --270

   SELECT dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,fdate),0) Month,-1*SUM(fqty) 'A270',
       (select -1*sum(fqty) 
        from M2MDATA01.dbo.intran t  INNER JOIN
             M2MDATA01.dbo.inmast m ON t.fpartno = m.fpartno INNER JOIN 
             M2MDATA01.dbo.jomast j ON t.ftojob = j.fjobno INNER JOIN
             M2MDATA01.dbo.inmast m2 on j.fpartno=m2.fpartno and j.fpartrev=m2.frev and j.fac=m2.fac
             --PEntries e ON j.fpartno = e.Sand 
        where dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,t.fdate),0) BETWEEN dateadd(month,-11,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,intran.fdate),0)) and dateadd(month,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,intran.fdate),0)) AND
             fdate>='6/1/2008' AND
              t.ftype = 'I' AND 
              (m.fdescript in('TECHNISET 6435 PART 2 339749','TECHNISET F6000 PART 1 347944') OR m.fdescript LIKE 'ACTIVATOR%')  AND 
              m2.fcusrchr2='270') 'A27011'

Into #270 
FROM   M2MDATA01.dbo.intran intran  INNER JOIN
       M2MDATA01.dbo.inmast inmast ON intran.fpartno = inmast.fpartno INNER JOIN 
       M2MDATA01.dbo.jomast jomast ON intran.ftojob = jomast.fjobno INNER JOIN
        M2MDATA01.dbo.inmast m2 on jomast.fpartno=m2.fpartno and jomast.fpartrev=m2.frev and jomast.fac=m2.fac
      -- PEntries ON jomast.fpartno = PEntries.Sand 
WHERE  dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,fdate),0) BETWEEN dateadd(month,-2,@date) and @date AND
       intran.ftype = 'I' AND 
      (inmast.fdescript in('TECHNISET 6435 PART 2 339749','TECHNISET F6000 PART 1 347944') OR inmast.fdescript LIKE 'ACTIVATOR%') AND 
       m2.fcusrchr2='270'
GROUP BY dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,fdate),0), dateadd(month,-11,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,intran.fdate),0)), dateadd(month,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,intran.fdate),0))
ORDER BY dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,fdate),0)
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I did not know that! I was just following the way previous writers of stored procedures at my office have named them, I will pass that on.

Comment: It is also a minor performance hit. When the engine sees sp_ it automatically looks first in msdb regardless of which database is currently being used. I agree 100000% with @marc_s that no prefix is the best choice.